# Profiling for Node.js Application

Tags: node.js, performance, profiling, v8, epoll

I followed this link https://nodejs.org/uk/docs/guides/simple-profiling/, to profile a particular endPoint in my app (Expressjs).

The endpoint will download a pdf from `s3` , use a thread pool  ( a pool of 4 worker_threads) to fill the pdf with data (I use `HummusJS` for pdf filling), then upload the filled file to s3  and respond with a `signedUrl` for the filled file.

The test was done by `apache benchmark`:

`ab -p req.json -T application/json   -c 20 -n 2000 http://{endpoint}`

The output from profilling was like this  :

```
 [Bottom up (heavy) profile]:
  Note: percentage shows a share of a particular caller in the total
  amount of its parent calls.
  Callers occupying less than 1.0% are not shown.

   ticks parent  name
  287597   89.2%  epoll_pwait
```

```
 [Bottom up (heavy) profile]:
  Note: percentage shows a share of a particular caller in the total
  amount of its parent calls.
  Callers occupying less than 1.0% are not shown.

   ticks parent  name
  1515166   98.5%  epoll_wait
```

So, my question is , what does the `epoll_wait` and `epoll_pwait` mean, since they are taking almost 100% of CPU time taken by the program ?

Answer (score 1):

See [google.com/search?q=epoll_wait](https://google.com/search?q=epoll_wait).

In short, the thread was waiting for something (maybe the network? maybe another thread?).